# When and where is the manifest file read?

Tags: android

On Android, when during the application's lifecyle is the manifest file read? Is it right after Zygote forks the process; is it done by the activity manager; or, is it done somewhere else?

If anyone can point me to the code responsible for this, or give me a good idea where to look, I'd greatly appreciate it. As it stands now, I'm a little stumped on when/where this happens.

Comment: "is it done somewhere else?" -- it has to be done at install time. Otherwise, Android will never fork a process for it, as Android would not know about any of the app's components.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Definitely, it needs to be done at install time, since the user must agree to what permissions the app requires. However, it has to also be done at some point when the app is run, otherwise, how else would the system know what permissions to give the app? I'm interested in the latter.

Comment: "how else would the system know what permissions to give the app?" -- I would think that this would be handled at install time. I have assumed that the manifest information is unpacked into some sort of database structure, whatever `PackageManager` is accessing behind the scenes (and over some Binder interface, I presume). But, you might want to grab [a book on Android internals](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do), as those sort of low-level details are probably in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of that book before. I'll give it a read.